# WordPress/WooCommerce (Backend) running too slow

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, woocommerce

I have eCommernce Web Site running on WordPress *v4.7.2* and WooCommerce. It was running good till last week but now Only the Backend is running too slow, where as on the other hand my frontend is running at a normal speed.

I just updated an Order Status which has 1 line item it took around 5-6 min.

Server stats at this point of time

- Physical Memory Usage => 198.1 / 2048 MB
- Entry Processes => 1 / 40
- Virtual Memory Usage => 173.7 / 1024 MB
- CPU Usage => 13 / 100%
- I/O Usage 0 / 4096 KB/s

I don't know why this is happening or what is causing it to take so much time to load WooCommerce related backend page other backend pages like post and page is also slow load time is around 10-20 second, not in min(s).

I google for this and I find that it might be because of Woo Session or `wp_option` size or caching plugin. but in my case tables has few data and I'm not using any cashing plugin.

- `wp_posts` => 2462 (record) with `AUTO_INCREMENT` => 2897
- `wp_options` => 1448 (record) with `AUTO_INCREMENT` => 41947
- `wp_woocommerce_sessions` => 27 (record) with `AUTO_INCREMENT` => 70246

List of plugin that I'm using

- All In One SEO Pack `Version 2.3.11.4`
- Custom Related Products for WooCommerce `Version 1.2`
- Mailgun `Version 1.5.8`
- Simple 301 Redirects `Version 1.07`
- WooCommerce `Version 2.6.14`
- WooCommerce Helper `Version 1.7.2`
- YITH WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter `Version 3.1.2`
- YITH WooCommerce Compare `Version 2.1.0`
- YITH WooCommerce Wishlist `Version 2.0.16`

Please Note:

1. I have no issue with my frontend load time.
2. Backend pages that are related to WooCommerce are only too slow.
3. When I updated order status it was around 1AM so the site visitor was fairly low.

**UPDATED** *v1*

#### WordPress Environment

Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Memory Limit: 512 MB
WP Cron: ✔

#### Server Environment

Server Info: Apache Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10 mod_bwlimited/1.4   mod_fcgid/2.3.9
PHP Version: 5.6.25
PHP Post Max Size: 32 MB
PHP Time Limit: 180
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
cURL Version: 7.36.0
OpenSSL/1.0.1e

SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.6.21
Max Upload Size: 32 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔

> Remote Post: x `wp_remote_post()` failed. PayPal IPN won't work with
>   your server. Contact your hosting provider. Error: cURL error 28:
>   Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
>
> Remote Get: x
>   `wp_remote_get()` failed. The WooCommerce plugin updater won't work with
>   your server. Contact your hosting provider. Error: cURL error 28:
>   Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds

I got this 2 error in WC System Status. I checked my `phpinfo(-1);` it is showing that `cURL` is enabled. Then what might be the reason that it cannot able to connect?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should provide also some information (regarding memory usage) and server php/mySql versions in woocommerce > System status (if there is something wrong related to your config, you will get red warnings). You can also increase the memory allocated to backend adding this `define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );` to your `wp_config.php` file… **After that the only way to find the guilty** is to disable all plugins (not woocommerce), and to enable them one by one, testing at each step your backend. Also the problem can be the theme, so try to switch to the default WP theme, to see.

Comment: thanks, @LoicTheAztec, for showing me the right direction I got 2 error in WC Status regarding `cURL` but I have that featured enabled, and moreover all the error_log are blank. I have updated my question can you please have a look at it, it would be great if you can assist me further.

Comment: he problem is surely an to old version of CURL and there is a lot of plugins that need a more recent version than the one you have… Now you have first to disable all plugins to see what happen and to enable / disable them 1 by 1… do that first (Make a backup before)…

Comment: ok @LoicTheAztec, I'll check it as you have said. thanks again.